# ArrayFormula retrieve list by multiple criterias

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

## Input

**Data sheet**

```
TaskId  ClientId Canceled
1             1         0
2             1         0
3             1         0
4             2         0
5             2         1
6             2         0
7             3         0
```

**Report sheet**

```
ClientId
1
1
2
3
```

## Desired Output

Arrayformula to get all TaskIds from Data by clients where Canceled = 0

```
TaskIds
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
6
7
```

---

I have `join` + `filter` formula to drag down, which gives me all TaskIds for clients:

```
ClientId  TaskIds
1          1,2,3
1          1,2,3
2          4,6
3          7
```

Then I get my result from this helper_column:

`=transpose(split(join(",", helper_colum)))`

And I want to make this work without need to drag down.

Comment: Are the result of  duplicate client IDs( Two 1s) necessary?

Comment: @anonymous, duplicate client IDs is necessary because the task is to make the workflow by pattern, and pattern may repeat.

Comment: Ok... If it weren't for the duplicates,a simple query would've done the trick. No matter now though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(""&TRANSPOSE(IF(TRANSPOSE(A11:A14)=B2:B8,IF(C2:C8=0,A2:A8,""),""))),"")))
```

A11:A14=Report sheet Client ID.
A2:C8=Data sheet values.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Accepted the answer because it is shorter, straightforward and (bonus!) gives no error when all tasks are canceled. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Report' tab [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K0FLuKDLJ5oZ_mgkHkUjwt-XacU17cplrCIMaK9t_u4/edit?usp=sharing), cell B2 I entered

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(A2:A5&"", regexreplace({unique(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0))&"", trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0)))=filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0))*len(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0)),filter(Data!A2:A, Data!C2:C=0)&",",),,50000)))},",$", ), 2, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! Took me 20 min. to get it. Why do we need `*len(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0))`? This formula worked too: `=arrayformula(vlookup(A2:A5&"", regexreplace({unique(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0))&"", trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(unique(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0)))=filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C=0)),filter(Data!A2:A, Data!C2:C=0)&",",),,50000)))},",$", ), 2, 0))`